# Passing Parameters to a Flow from a salesforce report

Tags: reporting, visual-workflow

We have a use case in which we need to be able to invoke a flow and also pass parameters from a salesforce report. Is there any way to do it ?.

If there is no direct way, I was thinking to invoke a Visualforce page and pass url parameters and then use those parameters to launch a flow and pass the parameters. 
   Please let me know of any suggestions.

Comment: Great question, I think Flow is still very much understated personally, growing fan of it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did this by adding custom formula field to my object e.g. 'Flow Action' and using the HYPERLINK formula function. Then i wrote a Report and included the field.

**Step 1. Create Custom Formula Field.**

[image]

[image]

**Step 2. Add it to a Report.**

[image]

**NOTE:** This approach allows you to use the full power of formula fields to define context specific Flow Actions, that start different flows based on the row data if needed.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot for the suggestion. I can bypass creating a Visualforce page with this approach. Thanks much for your suggestion. I think this approach will work in my use case.